# "Je l'aurais vu de mes propres yeux que je ne le croirais pas."

Tags: grammaire, sens, conjonctions

> Je l'aurais vu de mes propres yeux que je ne le croirais pas.

J’ai du mal à comprendre cette phrase. Je comprends *Je l'aurais vu de mes propres yeux* et je comprends *je ne le croirais pas*, mais au total cela ne me dit rien. Pourriez-vous reformuler cette phrase ou la traduire en anglais ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Même si je l’avais vu de mes propres yeux, je ne le croirais pas davantage.
- Even if I had seen it with my own eyes, I still wouldn’t believe it.
  Had I seen it with my own eyes, I still wouldn’t believe it.

**Je l’aurais vu** → conditionnel → je suppose un état de la réalité pour lequel j’aurais été témoin de la chose.

**que** → en assumant vraie l’affirmation précédente, il y aurait la conséquence qui suivra (c’est-à-dire, je n’y croirais pas plus que maintenant).

---

#### Un peu plus de détails

On remarque que la première condition n’est pas introduite par un marqueur conditionnel *(si, même si)*. *Le Bon usage* traite de ce cas particulier où la sous-phrase conditionnelle est placée en tête de phrase, auquel cas le marqueur n’est pas obligatoire. On y présente quelques exemples littéraires de structure similaire à celle proposée dans la question :

> Seraient-ils neuf cent quatre-vingt-quinze millions et moi tout seul, c’est eux qui ont tort
>     <sub>— *Voyage au bout de la nuit,* Céline</sub>
>
> Vous m’offririez des fleurs, je les refuserais !
>     <sub>— *Celles qu’on prend dans ses bras,* Montherlant</sub>

Comment: "Had I seen it with my own eyes, I still wouldn't HAVE believed it" ... same goes for the other one with "if".

Comment: @Mat That such a minor glitch could cause a negative vote blows my mind, but let me nevertheless explain what’s going on in the mind of a French-speaking person: the sense that what was witnessed is not real maintains the disbelief into the future, so that **even now**, when the events are part of the past, I still don’t believe what I saw was real. This is what is conveyed by the French version. The statement that disbelief drags in time has more weight than simply stating one didn’t believe it as it was happening.

Comment: I think you missed the point here and beg to differ: "Même si je l’avais vu de mes propres yeux, je n'y aurais pas cru davantage." That's way better for any French person. The version to be translated sounds very old, even incorrect... English and French are similar here. If I had done...I would have done...=  si j'avais fait... j'aurais fait (not je ferais...). OR je l'aurais vu, j'y aurais pas cru... You need AVOIR in both parts. If you want to remove avoir : "Je le verrais que je le croirais pas..." this is proper grammar. It's not about how one might see it or perception per se...(⚆_⚆)

Comment: It's about Concordance des temps ;)

Comment: @Mat Il s’agit plutôt d'une explication, pas d'une manière de dire. Je suis allé en long pour bien faire comprendre ce que ça implique comme signification, pas pour recommender officiellement la version longue. L'OP veut savoir comment analyser la phrase, inutile d'en offrir des versions abrégées. La phrase qu'il propose est correcte, mais sa signification lui échappait un peu. Il y a dans la phrase une continuité dans le fait de ne pas y croire. Il faut comprendre ce que l'on veut dire plutôt que d'appliquer des recettes de concordances des temps.

Comment: Je comprends bien mais l'un n'empêche pas l'autre. Je ne nie pas votre approche explicative, je rajoute simplement une approche grammaticale. Car comprendre la grammaire et donc la concordance des temps, est également important car c'est aussi comprendre les liens entre les phrases (ou groupes de mots) et leur suite logique...

Answer (score 0):

A good english translation would be:

> I would have seen it with my own eyes, that I wouldn't believe it.

or:

> Even if I would have seen it with my own eyes, I wouldn't believe it.

It can be used as an answer for instance if one of your friends is talking about ghosts or **unbelievable events**.

Comment: This is not a good English translation; it's a very poorly formed conditional clause, and it's not clear what it means in English.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for your feedback, I updated my sentence accordingly, and also added an other one as an alternative.

Answer (score -3):

La présente tournure est reconnue dans le dictionnaire de l'Ac. comme étant [*vieillie*](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/QUE?options=motExact).

> (Ac.) –Que introduit une subordonnée circonstancielle de conséquence (vieilli).
>
> - Ils boivent que c'en est honteux.
> - Il reviendrait que la situation s'arrangerait immédiatement.

On peut donc reformuler cela comme suit ;

- En conséquence de l'avoir vu de mes propres yeux je ne le croirais pas. (*style lourd, à éviter, voir commentaires (user **jlliagre**))

En anglais cela peut se dire ainsi :

- «  Would I have seen it with my own eyes I still wouldn't believe it. ».

Comment: La phrase faisant l'objet de la question est peut-être vieillie, mais je la trouve tout à fait acceptable et idiomatique. En revanche, *En conséquence de l'avoir vu de mes propres yeux je ne le croirais pas* n'est pas du tout idiomatique. Proposer une phrase aussi bancale en remplacement d'une phrase parfaitement correcte est aberrant.

Comment: @jlliagre Il n'y a aucun jugement porté sur la phrase  et le seul porté sur la tournure est celle de l'Ac. "Reformulation" ne signifie pas "remplacement", et vise essentiellement à mettre en valeur l'analyse grammaticale qu'avance le dictionnaire, comme sans l'aide de ce dictionnaire on peut facilement se tromper sur la relation de conséquence que la tournure introduit de façon consistante. Finalement, il n'y a pas de question d'idiomaticité mais dans le contexte donné je reconnais qu'il s'agit d'un style lourd, à éviter.

Comment: "Would I" est formellement interdit en anglais si ce n'est pour la forme interrogative. (Ce qui n'est pas le cas ici)

Comment: @Ced Ce que je crois c'est que ce n'est pas de l'anglais ordinaire mais je ne suis pas sûr qu'il sois strictement confiné à la langue littéraire; dans la langue littéraire anglaise, cependant, il me semble que l'on trouve bien cette tournure « inversion auxiliaire pronom » et elle est équivalente à « If I had »; pour « Would I have told you, what difference would it make? » DeepL renvoie « Je te l'aurais dit, quelle différence il y aurait ? »; vous pensez que c'est une coïncidence? (champ 1)

Comment: @Ced Il est possible qu'une notion étrangère se soit insinuée dans mon anglais, mais j'en doute; je vais devoir attendre une preuve solide de l'erreur, s'il y a erreur. Je n'ai pas les moyens de produire une telle preuve moi-même malheureusement.

Comment: I think the translation in English is faulty. (No negative vote). I think you are influenced by the turn Had I not been there,  I would not have believed it (I think so but I am not quite sure). May be you should ask a question in ESE.

Comment: @Dimitris According to a small research I just made "would" is quite possibly one of those forms for which the inversion is allowed so as to mean "if"" (should, had, would); here is what I find: (Bittersweet Nightshade, p. 93) *Would I have known* there was a lady present, I would have greeted you correctly.” At that, the knight waded slowly into the water, with his armor clanking, towards the center where Cheshire sat worriedly. The knight stopped and looked back ...

Comment: @Dimitris Bittersweet Nightshade, Yew Baneberry (2007) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would+i+have+known%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=wvU7XeGWGIm_UKaGtLAC&start=90&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjh__XVwtTjAhWJHxQKHSYDDSY4UBDy0wMIiwE&biw=2144&bih=1122&dpr=0.9 Thanks for the stimulus, it got me going !